# 302-redirect domain to subfolder

Tags: prestashop, http-status-code-302

My client's domain (camocamo.com) is 302-redirected to the subfolder camocamo.com/fi/. I want to change this into an 301-redirect, but I cannot figure out how. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. The site is built on PrestaShop. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As i seen in https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/387556-editing-htaccess-for-301-redirects-to-new-site-urls/
, try adding a redict rule in `.htaccess` file in apache root directory, putting your rewrite cond below this code:

```
# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

The line could be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 / http://camocamo.com/fi/
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I got a message saying "too many redirects, could not load the site".

Comment: The rule may be in conflict with another one in the .htaccess file (circular reference maybe). Can you see another rule like this in the file?

Comment: It turned out to be much easier than I expected. There is a switch in PrestaShop, that allows you to choose between 301 and 302 redirects. I switched it into 301 and voila! problem solved. :-) Many thanks again for your time and consideration. Appreciate it.